# Ender 5 won't lift the Z-Axis before printing

Tags: troubleshooting, z-axis, creality-ender-5

I've had an Ender 5 for about a year without problems. But just recently, the printer is not lifting the Z-axis before printing. It will home great but when it moves to print the purge line it lifts the bed down about 2-3 millimeters and the nozzle is not even close to touching the bed anymore.

I've checked the starting G-code in Cura and it all looks fine but I'm still having problems.

Current Start G-code:

```
M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00 ;Setup machine max acceleration
M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E50.00 ;Setup machine max feedrate
M204 P500.00 R1000.00 T500.00 ;Setup Print/Retract/Travel acceleration
M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E5.00 ;Setup Jerk
M220 S100 ;Reset Feedrate
M221 S100 ;Reset Flowrate

G28 ;Home

G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to start position
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.20 F1500.0 E15 ;Draw the first line
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.20 F5000.0 ;Move to side a little
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.20 F1500.0 E30 ;Draw the second line
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
M503
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of testing (which included reinstalling firmware, formatting various SD cards, and changing G-code and slicer settings), I did find a function to restore factory defaults and that did the trick. I'm still not sure how something wrong got stored in the memory but it did and resetting to factory defaults worked.

Comment: Can you tell me how you got it factory reset. My 5 pro I can't figure out how to get original firmware back. I installed a bltouch and formware and that messed everything up and now my bed goes all the way to the bottom of the machine instead of the top. Ive disconnected the bltouch and can't get it to work right now

Comment: @Carter, if you could [edit] and expand upon your answer, w.r.t. where you found the function to restore factory defaults (maybe with screen shots, if appropriate), then that would be most useful. Thanks. Oh, and maybe mark your answer as the accepted answer as well, using the tick icon.

Comment: Not sure what firmware ur using and what setup you have so here’s a few answers. First, you can type the gcode commands M502 (to reset factory defaults) and M500 (to save) in a text file and stick it into the printer (I believe it should read the commands instantly). Second, if you are running Octoprint, you can input those same commands in the terminal of Octoprint. Third, there should be a function perhaps under Configuration that should restore factory defaults. Finally, as a catch all, you can go to the Creality website and download the original software to send to the printer via SD card.