# Ender 5 start problems

Tags: creality-ender-5

I've had an Ender 5 for a while now and it worked phenomenally but recently I installed a BigTreeTech SKR E3 mini and I had to update the firmware as well which came with some problems I don't know how to fix.

Whenever I start a print, it'll home fine but then move the nozzle up way too much (about 10 mm) off the build plate. In a recent post, I found out restoring factory defaults fixes it temporarily but I have to do that on every print and I really need to find a change that will permanently fix it.

I'm currently running Marlin 2.0x and my start G-code is listed in the other post ([Ender 5 won't lift the Z-Axis before printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/17951/ender-5-wont-lift-the-z-axis-before-printing)). Does anybody have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the firmware from Marlin 2.0x in the BigTreeTech GitHub to the Marlin bugfix-2.0x in the Marlin GitHub.

I also removed my Ender 5 from my Cura profile and added it again so it would reset any G-code I potentially messed up while tinkering. So far it is printing great.